# Optimization SQL for getting data from two joined tables (usernames for user-from-id and user-to-id msgs from two tables)

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have table "msgs" with messages between users (their ids):

```
+--------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+
| msg_id |user_from_id | user_to_id | message | room_id |
+--------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 1      |           1 |          4 |Hello!   |       2 |
| 2      |           1 |          5 |Hi there |       1 |
| 3      |           2 |          1 |CU soon  |       2 |
| 4      |           3 |          7 |nice...  |       1 |
+--------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

I also have two tables with users names.
Table: user1

```
+--------+----------+
|user_id |user_name |
+--------+----------+
| 5      | Ann      |
| 6      | Sam      |
| 7      | Michael  |
+--------+----------+
```

Table: user2

```
+--------+----------+
|user_id |user_name |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | John     |
| 2      | Alice    |
| 3      | Tom      |
| 4      | Jane     |
+--------+----------+
```

I need to get usernames for two users IDs in every row. Every user-id can be in first or second table with usernames.

I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  m.msg_id,
  m.user_from_id,
  CASE WHEN c1.user_name IS NULL THEN c3.user_name ELSE c1.user_name END AS from_name,
  m.user_to_id,
  CASE WHEN c2.user_name IS NULL THEN c4.user_name ELSE c2.user_name END AS to_name,
  m.message
FROM msgs m
LEFT JOIN users1 c1 ON c1.user_id=m.user_from_id
LEFT JOIN users1 c2 ON c2.user_id=m.user_to_id
LEFT JOIN users2 c3 ON c3.user_id=m.user_from_id
LEFT JOIN users2 c4 ON c4.user_id=m.user_to_id
WHERE m.room_id=1
LIMIT 0, 8
```

It works.
Execute query to get raw data without usernames (without any join) tooks about ~0.1 sec. But it's enough to join only one usernames table (user1 or user2 only) to get this data in about ~6.2 sec. (with join one table). I have quite a lot rows in this tables: 35K rows in msgs, 0.5K in user1, 25K in user2.
Executing query with join two tables (with all this data) is impossible.

**How to optimize this query? I just need usernames for user_ids in first "msgs" table.**

Comment: Why do you have two tables of users?

Comment: @eggyal, good question ;) but in above example I just simplify data structure. I know that that is not the best solution, but it's impossible in this project to have all this data in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are potentially many differences between the queries with and without the joins.  I am going to assume that the `id`s have the appropriate indexes -- primary keys automatically do.  If not, then check that.

The obvious solution is to use the original query as a subquery:

```
SELECT m.msg_id, m.user_from_id,
       (CASE WHEN c1.user_name IS NULL THEN c3.user_name ELSE c1.user_name
        END) AS from_name,
       m.user_to_id,
       (CASE WHEN c2.user_name IS NULL THEN c4.user_name ELSE c2.user_name
        END) AS to_name,
       m.message
FROM (SELECT m.*
      FROM msgs m
      WHERE m.room_id = 1
      LIMIT 0, 8
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     users1 c1
     ON c1.user_id = m.user_from_id LEFT JOIN
     users1 c2
     ON c2.user_id = m.user_to_id LEFT JOIN
     users2 c3
     ON c3.user_id = m.user_from_id LEFT JOIN
     users2 c4
     ON c4.user_id = m.user_to_id;
```

For most data structures, the `distinct` is also unnecessary.

This also makes (the reasonable assumption) that `user_id` is unique in the users tables.

Also, use of `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is highly discouraged.  The particular rows you get are indeterminate and might change from one execution to the next.

Comment: When I have duplicated records you query returns more than 8 rows. I added LIMIT 0, 8 at the end of your query. In oryginal query i use ORDER By clause, ordering by date.
Thank you Gordon! 
On my local server on my old notebook with DISTINCT this query is executed in 18.8 sec. (without ORDER BY, but with ORDER by 10 sec.) and without ~0.5 sec. 
It's better now.